# Full House order ranking Eights full of Nines vs Nines Full of Fives

Tags: full-house

See the first line in the picture. I got 3 Nines and 2 Fives and my opponent got 3 eights and 2 Nines.

I thought the triplet was ranked first and thought I would have won the hand. Why did I lose?

[image: See First Line]

Comment: There's not enough information here to tell. Are you playing Omaha?

Comment: if your playing Omaha you do not have a full house

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're playing Omaha. If that's the case, then Omaha hands are made from *exactly two* of your four cards plus *exactly three* from the board. So you cannot play the 9 and both 5s from your hand. You don't show your opponent's hand, but I assume it contains two 8s, in which case he plays them along with 8 9 9 on the board for a full house.

Comment: ^this. You must use 2 pocket (hole) cards and 3 community cards in Omaha.